# Convert Thymeleaf "th:field" in Freemarker

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, freemarker

I convert my project from Thymeleaf to Freemaker. I have one problem. Now I’ll try to describe it.

On the main page of my site there are list of vendors and a search field that searches for vendors by name.

In Thymeleaf it looks something like this-

**Controller:**

```
 @GetMapping("/vendors")
public String getAllVendors(Model model,@PageableDefault Pageable pageable){
    Page<Vendors> vendors = vendorRepository.findAll(pageable);
    model.addAttribute("searchVendor",new Foo()); //This is for search field
    model.addAttribute("url","/vendors");
    model.addAttribute("vendors",vendors);

    return "vendors/list";
}
```

Foo class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo {
    private List<Long> checkedItems; // for checkboxes
    private List<Long> checkedItemsPlus; //for checkboxes
    private String findItem; // to find by the name
    private Long findSupply; // to find by the id
    private String findItemPlus; // to find by the second name
}
```

**Thymeleaf template (form for search field):**

```
 <form th:action="@{/showVendor}" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <input type="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
      th:field="${searchVendor.findItem}" placeholder="Search By Name"/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
         Search
      </button>
  </form>
```

> ${searchVendor.findItem}-this is the string in which the entered name
>   is written.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/showVendor")
public String getVendorBySearch(Model model,@ModelAttribute("searchVendor") Foo foo){

model.addAttribute("vendors",
      vendorService.getVendorByName(foo.getFindItem()));

return "vendors/show";
```

}

Thats all works fine with Thymeleaf.

In Freemaker i changed only my thymeleaf template -

**Freemaker template**

```
 <form action="/showVendor" method="post" class="form-inline">
     <input type="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" value="${searchVendor.findItem}" id="findItem" name="findItem" placeholder="Search By Name"/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
 </form>
```

> I'm not sure about that, but replaced **th:field** on **value, id, name**
>
> Then i click button i have this error-

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Nov 07 21:42:23 MSK 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
```

> **And my final questions.How to replace th:field from Thymeleaf to
>   Freemaker? Did I do it right or i need to do something else? Why does this error come?**

Comment: Freemarker is a simpler system than Thymeleaf, and I don't think it has the concept of model binding.

Comment: So how can I pass the entered value from my search field  to the controller? Do you know?